Multiple-cucumber-html-reporter for Cypress Cucumber Framework is not generating HTML Report with attached failed screenshot
Objective: My objective is to generate HTML Report for my cypress cucumber framework with attached failed screenshots
I am using multiple-cucumber-html-reporter for generating an html report, but it fails to provide me with an attached screenshot for failed steps.
My Dependencies:
  "devDependencies": {
    "cypress": "^13.9.0",
    "cypress-cucumber-attach-screenshots-to-failed-steps": "^1.0.0",
    "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.3.1",
    "multiple-cucumber-html-reporter": "^3.6.2"

My Current Folder Structure:

I have created a cucumber-html-report.js file in the support/ folder to generate the html report.
const report = require("multiple-cucumber-html-reporter");
report.generate({
  jsonDir: "./cypress/reports/cucumber-json/",
  reportPath: "./cypress/reports/html-report/",
  openReportInBrowser:true,
  metadata: {
    browser: {
      name: "chrome",
      version: "124",
    },
    device: "Laptop",
    platform: {
      name: "Windows",
      version: "11",
    },
  },
  customData: {
    title: "Run info",
    data: [
      { label: "Project", value: "Demo New Tours" },
      { label: "Release", value: "Version-0" },
      { label: "Execution Start Time", value: "Nov 19th 2024, 05:00 PM IST" },
      { label: "Execution End Time", value: "Nov 19th 2024, 05:30 PM IST" },
    ],
  },
});

I don't see json parameters to attach the screenshot in the above mentioned ucumber-html-report.js file from (https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiple-cucumber-html-reporter)
Solutions I tried:
I tried using the npm dependency "cypress-cucumber-attach-screenshots-to-failed-steps".
I did work at the first try, but after that it stopped attaching the screenshot.

It might be possible that this dependency is old and is now not supported with current cypress dependencies.
Next, I tried attaching the below code to my e2e.js file as a afterEach hook.
//Attach Screenshots to Cucumber HTML Report

afterEach(() => {
    const screenshotsFolder = Cypress.config("screenshotsFolder");
    if (window.cucumberJson?.generate) {
        const testState = window.testState;
        const stepResult = testState.runTests[testState.currentScenario.name][testState.currentStep];
        if (stepResult?.status === "failed") {
            const screenshotFileName = '${testState.feature.name} -- ${testState.currentScenario.name} (failed).png';
            cy.readFile('${screenshotsFolder}/${Cypress.spec.name}/${screenshotFileName}', 'base64').then((imgData) => {
                stepResult.attachment = {
                    data: imgData,
                    media: { type: "image/png" },
                    index: testState.currentStep,
                    testCase: testState.formatTestCase(testState.currentScenario),
                };
            });

        }
    }
});

I am facing the below error for the afterEach hook:
  2) Register to the NewDemoTours Website with valid data
       "after each" hook for "Register as new user with valid data":
     CypressError: `cy.readFile("${screenshotsFolder}/${Cypress.spec.name}/${screenshotFileName}")` timed out.

https://on.cypress.io/readfile

Because this error occurred during a `after each` hook we are skipping all of the remaining tests.
      at cypressErr (https://demo.guru99.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:75611:18)
      at Object.cypressErrByPath (https://demo.guru99.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:75616:10)
      at $Command.readFile (https://demo.guru99.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:119862:88)
      at cyFn (https://demo.guru99.com/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:138923:19)
  From Your Spec Code:
      at Context.eval (cypress/support/e2e.js:32:101)


Even the screenshot is not getting attached!

It would be really helpful if someone helps me to resolve this afterEach hook error, or provide a possible solution to attach my failed screenshots to my HTML reports.

Your readFile code is incorrect, it should be using the back-tick character instead of the single-quote character as delimieter.
cy.readFile(`${screenshotsFolder}/${Cypress.spec.name}/${screenshotFileName}`, 'base64')

// or just concat the strings 

cy.readFile(screenshotsFolder +'/'+ Cypress.spec.name +'/'+ screenshotFileName, 'base64')


Hi @SReilly, I have used the "back-tick" the code still fails giving the same error.

The error shows the raw template string cy.readFile("${screenshotsFolder}/${Cypress.spec.name}..., so clearly you have not followed this solution correctly.
